# how to limit cache memory ubuntu?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I have written a C++ code which I have to run on many low configuration computers. Now, my PC is very high configuration. I am using Ubuntu 10.04 & I set hard limit on some resources i.e. on memory & virtual memory. Now my question is:

1) how to set limit on the cache size and  cache line size ? 
2) what other limits I should put to check my code is OK or not ?

I am using command:

```
ulimit -H -m 1000000
ulimit -H -v 500000
```

Comment: Is this a programming question or an administration question? Because as it's worded it's an administration question and would be better asked on http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't limit cache size, that's a (mostly transparent) hardware feature.

The good news is this shouldn't matter, since you can't run out of cache - it just spills and your program runs more slowly.

If your concern is avoiding spills, you could investigate `valgrind --tool=cachegrind` - it may be possible to examine the likely behaviour on your target hardware cache.

Answer (score 1):

To PROPERLY simulate running on low-end machines (although not with low cache-limits), you can run the code in a virtual machine rather than the real hardware of your machine. This will show you what happens on a machine with small memory much more than if you limit using `ulimit`, as `ulimit` simply limits what YOUR application will get. So it shows that your application doesn't run out of memory when running a particular set of tests. But it doesn't show how the application and system behaves together when there isn't a huge amount of memory in the first place.

A machine with low amount of physical memory will behave quite differently when it comes to for example swapping behaviour, and filesystem caching, just to mention a couple of things that change between a "large memory, but application is limited" vs "small memory in the first place".

I'm not sure if Ubuntu comes with any flavour of Virtual Machine setup, but for example VirtualBox is pretty easy to configure and set up on any Linux/Windows machine. As long as you have a modern enough processor to run hardware virtualization instructions.

As Useless not at all uselessly stated, cache-memory will not "run out" or in any other way cause a failure. It will run a little slower, but not massive amounts (about 10x for any given operation, but this will be averaged over a large number of other instructions in most cases, unless you are really working hard at proving how important cache is, such as very large matrix multiplications).

One tip might also be to look around for some old hardware. There are usually computers for sale that are several years old, for next to nothing at a "computer recycling shop" or similar. Set such a system up, install your choice of OS, and see what happens.